# Converting String of ASCII character values to actual string in swift 2 (latest beta)

Tags: string, swift, functional-programming, swift2

There are various posts on similar subjects but I have yet to find exactly what I'm looking for

I have a string of ASCII character values which can be converted into a string

For example if i have

```
let asciiString = "45 56 54 44 45 52 52 44 50 49 57 49 44 49 52"
```

then ultimately it should convert to

```
let resultString = "-86,-44,2191,14"
```

#### Work thus far...

So here is what I have so far

```
let asciiStringWithSpaces = "45 56 54 44 45 52 52 44 50 49 57 49 44 49 52"

// Convert string into array
let asciiArray = split(asciiStringWithSpaces.characters) { $0 == " "}.map(String.init)

print(asciiArray)

// Convert into an array of Characters
let charArray = Array(asciiArray).map{ String(Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32($0)!))) }

// Convert into an array of Strings
let stringArray = Array(asciiArray).map{ Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32($0)!))}

// What do i do now?  -
```

I tried to use Reduce to combine all the strings but couldn't seem to get things working correctly.

I'm using Xcode 7 Beta 4

Comment: given the initial string and the result string that you presented, these are not hex values but rather are decimal values of ASCII characters - I have submitted an edit to reflect that fact

Comment: oops you are correct and i rejected your edits.  sorry!

Comment: edit resubmitted  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `charArray` is an array of `String`, and your `stringArray` is
an array of `Character`, so there seems to be something mixed-up.

Anyway, you can use the array of characters, slightly simplified to

```
let charArray = asciiArray.map { Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32($0)!)) }
```

and then create a string from that array:

```
let string = String(charArray)
print(string)
// -86,-44,2191,14
```